# Table will not load into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've tried loading a table into BigQuery with no success. The error message I continue to get is attached below and I've tried manually entering my data along with letting Google determine my data as well and neither work.

Here is my error messages:

> Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 11, but line starting at position:606 contains only 1 columns.

> Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 0; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0

And here is my schema:

```
Product_Type - String
Product_Name - String
Size - String
Manufacturer - String
SKU - String
NDC - String
Price - Float
UOM - String
Alt_UOM_Price - Float
Alt_UOM - String
Net_Price - Float
NEt_UOM - String
```

Comment: How about looking at the line in your source data that the error message refers to? You appear to have malformed data.

Comment: As far as I can tell, my data seems pretty standard and could not notice any issues with it. I did pull this data from another company's price sheet though.

Comment: Also, I'm very new to bigquery and all of this in general. Can you please explain to me what line in my source data the error message is pointing to?

Comment: `line starting at position:606 contains only 1 columns` - So, the line starting from the 606th character of the file.

Comment: Gotcha, so I was just told that I needed to convert my file to a CSV and I did. Now I'm getting an error message stating: Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 429. Error: Missing close double quote (") character.
Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0

Comment: Also, I checked all of my float columns and I only have numbers within these columns.

Comment: Without and the file, we can't diagnose what is wrong with the file.  Create a smaller file, using sample data from the original and see if you can replicate the issue.  That may in itself show you what's wrong, but if not it lets you post that sample file in your question, and we can point out what's wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share my file as it contains confidential info but I appreciate the help you've given me. I'll try and figure this out on my own from here.

Comment: That is ***SPECIFICALLY*** why I said to see if you can ***REPLICATE*** that issue.  If you can't do that with dummy data, you've got a fundamental problem with regards to how you're going to test your code.  You do test your code, right?  Without personal/confidential/sensitive data?  Like unit-tests, integration tests, regression-tests, etc?  ***Replicate the problem with made up data, inspired by the real-world failure, but only containing the features that cause the failure, and share THAT...***  *(You're not the only person unable to share real-world data, yet we all manage; dummy-data!)*

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling `Jagged rows` when importing:

[image]

Comment: Tried jagged rows, did not seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I was also facing the same issue, with around 1713 rows with errors but by going to advanced options and ignoring the errors, it worked. Still, strange, couldn't understand what was wrong as the data in pandas looked okay!